# How to handle percentage values from read.csv in R?

Tags: r, csv

I read a large dataset from a `.csv` file where all values are stored as percentage, which leads all the corresponding values are characters in R such that:

```
df<-data.frame(v1=seq(1,3,1),
    v2=c("35.2%","11.1%","21.3%"),
    v3=c("23.6%","18.9%","34.8%"))
> df
  v1    v2    v3
1  1 35.2% 23.6%
2  2 11.1% 18.9%
3  3 21.3% 34.8%
```

Does anybody know what's the best way to format the `df` to be in numeric like this:

```
  v1   v2   v3
1  1 35.2 23.6
2  2 11.1 18.9
3  3 21.3 34.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

```
for(i in 2:3){
   df[ ,i] <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", x=df[ , i]))
}
```

Comment: `as.character` and `fixed=T` are unnecessary here, but good solution.